# Simulink model interface to external C++ application

Tags: simulink

I have a fairly complex Simulink model with multiple referenced models that I am trying to interface with external C++ code. I am using 2014a and generating code using Simulink Coder. Below are two important requirements I would like to satisfy while doing this:

1. Have the ability to create multiple instances of the model in my
   external C++ code.
2. Have the ability to overwrite data that is input to the model and
   have it reflected to the external application.

Given these requirements, at the top level what is the best method to interface to external IO, datastores or IO ports?

From my understanding using datastores (or Simulink.Signal objects) and by specifying the appropriate storage class I may be able to satisfy 2 above, but in doing so I would have to specify signal names and this would not allow me to satisfy 1.

If I use IO port blocks at top level, I may be able to satisfy 1 but not 2.

Update: #2 constraint has been removed due to design change. Hence the io port approach works for me.

Comment: This is a really tough one.
You want to instantiate your top model multiple times? Or one of the sub-referenced models?
Have you tried using C++ namespaces in your generated code?

Comment: Thanks for the response pmb. Yes using namespaces was the only option left for us. However at this we have the flexibility of making design changes and we can avoid the constraint of updating the external input from within the model. So using the io port approach works for me.